# Post to an API using OAuth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, oauth

I'm trying to post to an API.  The API takes files and converts them to JSON

Here is what I am doing:

```
consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new(consumer_key,secret, :site => uri)
accesstoken = OAuth::AccessToken.new(consumer, core_access_token, core_access_secret)

params = {:body => { 
              :binaryData => data, 
              :extension => "txt", 
              :locale => 'en_gb', 
              :instanceType => 'xray', 
              :fieldList => {"field" => ["All"]}
            }.to_json,
            :headers => { 
              'Accept' => 'application/json',
              'Content-Type' => 'application/json' ,
              }
            }
result = accesstoken.post(action, params)
```

And I get back the response:

```
<Net::HTTPBadRequest 400 Bad Request readbody=true>
```

What does this error mean? Wrong URI? Wrong access tokens? or Incorrect usage of the OAUTH Gem (ie, my code is wrong)

Comment: Why are you calling to_json there? Just passing a hash should suffice

Comment: Ok, but.  removing to_json does not change the response.

Comment: Can you provide an actual HTTP request? Either from network trace, server logs or client side logging?

Comment: There isn't any client side logging as it isn't posting from the browser, the API server logs aren't available to me and rails isn't logging any network trace type stuff.  Not sure where else to look?

Comment: 400 error usually means that your request is malformed. Most likely it didn't even get to the OAuth logic on the server. Try setting your params to just: { 
              'Accept' => 'application/json',
              'Content-Type' => 'application/json' ,
              }

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be like this:

```
consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new(consumer_key,secret, :site => uri)
accesstoken = OAuth::AccessToken.new(consumer, core_access_token, core_access_secret)

headers => { 
          'Accept' => 'application/json',
          'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
          }

result = accesstoken.post(action, data, headers)
```

Comment: headers = {etc...}  surely...  I took this and worked on the code and got a new error. 405 Not Allowed.  Which seems closer.

Comment: That is server specific. What service are you using? They must have an explanation of error codes. Maybe they only allow PUT/GET and not POST.

Comment: apparently my posts aren't reaching the server at all.  is that possible? what else could be generating the 405 error?

Comment: No, 405 must be coming from a server. What service are u using?

Comment: Burning Glass, which is a CV parsing service.